# rails uninitialized constant controller param

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller, parameters

I added an attribute to a model `:roleid` I have ran migrations and confirmed it is in the database. The error is happening in the controller.

Only, when I input a value into the form, it throws the error: `uninitialized constant User::Roleid`

It highlights the line `@user = User.new(user_params)` from the create action:

`user_params` is defined as the following:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:id, :email, :encrypted_password, :fname, :lname, :roleid)
```

As you can see, `roleid` exists:

```
mysql> DESCRIBE users;
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email                  | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI |         |                |
| encrypted_password     | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| reset_password_token   | varchar(255) | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| reset_password_sent_at | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| remember_created_at    | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sign_in_count          | int(11)      | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| current_sign_in_at     | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_sign_in_at        | datetime     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| current_sign_in_ip     | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| last_sign_in_ip        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at             | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at             | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| fname                  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname                  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| roleid                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The full error text is:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2016-03-17 17:23:31 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"48xz8D0jngCGOnL7qn4A93X2qeOcmvcE8QjXah7cjsxusA7FrPK8JhmVjRNa2nflkg4qfLs5cnL2oL9cHn/iUQ==", "user"=>{"id"=>"4", "email"=>"wlrg", "encrypted_password"=>"[FILTERED]", "fname"=>"flh", "lname"=>"wflh", "roleid"=>"4"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

NameError (uninitialized constant User::Roleid):
  app/controllers/users_controller.rb:27:in `create'
```

The controller code looks like:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Do you have `belongs_to` associations defined on `User`?

Comment: @spickermann how did you know that? genius! that was it